# Ignore platform requirements for sample data installation using Composer

Tags: magento2, composer, sample-data

I have a module installed via Composer where the latest master version requires PHP 7.0.x, while the updated version I'm using allows PHP 7.1.x which I have installed.

This causes a problem that on each `composer update`, it gives a platform requirement error. This can easily be solved by adding `--ignore-platform-reqs` to the command.

However, I want to install some stuff with Composer using Magento 2 CLI. Specifically, the sample data:

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Gives the Composer error that the PHP version is incorrect.

> [my_module x.x.x] requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP vers                              ion (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.

Is there a way to ignore platform requirements while deploying sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `sampledata:deploy` is mapped to `Magento\SampleData\Console\Command\SampleDataDeployCommand::execute`.

inside this method you will find a variable `$commonArgs = ['--working-dir' => $baseDir, '--no-progress' => 1];`

You can add `--ignore-platform-reqs=>1` in this array.

Of course you should do a plugin for this method and not edit the core.
If it's for test / debug purposes you can edit it temporarily.